# Can't Install after sharing it another mobile

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I made an Android app using Android studio, deployed and ran it directly by using my mobile running Oreo.
It installed successfully. But later I tired to share the APK from my mobile to other mobiles. But none of them are able to Install it.
However, if I build the APK and share the app-debug.apk to other mobiles. It Installs successfully.

I can't build APK and share app-debug.apk it everyone. 
I usually deploy it in my mobile, share APK(which used to work before)

Can anyone please help

Please excuse typos, I have typed from mobile.

Comment: There is difference in built apk and deployed apk. look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41471102/7910735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a signing issue. Is your app signed? The default signing is the debug signing. When you just build and deploy or run it on a connected device, it is signed by default as a debug sign.

If it is **not** uniquely signed, then running or installing on other devices might not be possible. Look at the app signing instruction and guide by Google, [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing), if you wish to distribute your app on other devices.

Another problem might be in the security authorization of other devices. Your device on which you are building has the developer options turned on. To run and install unsigned apps you'll need to activate the developer options in the device you want to run it on. Look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) about Developer Options and how to turn it on.

Comment: Hopefully, your statement didnt solve the problem, But the google doc link you shared really helped.

Answer (score 0):

by default the Android Studio packages just the needed files and installs the app in your mobile. If you share to other mobiles, the app will not install in few devices due to a few reasons like OS version, files mismatch, SHA keys mismatch, etc.

However, if you build the APK and share, the APK is equipped to be installed in any device starting from the minimum SDK version to the target SDK version.

Comment: Build APK, It creates a app-debug.apk. which is built for debug purpose and is not secure.